# Stuck with Core Data object graph Handling

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm having an object graph which contains several entities. i'm facing a situation where one entity can change several times but i need a way to revert it to the original state. Using some kind of undo/redo will probably not work well since other entities could change as well but i dont want to revert them.

I was thinking to just insert the changed object "naked" without any relationships. So the original one will stay in the object Graph and the changes will be floating alone.

Another way would be to change my Model so the object would be an Array. Within this i could save both and add some kind of identifier to recognize the appropriate object. However sometimes i need to replace the whole Graph and then i need to merge the changes.

I really feeling stuck with this Problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your model?

Comment: You might try with two `NSManagedObjectContext`s: the parent where all the related objects change without *undo*, and the child, where your object can change, but you can discard without affecting the others (or save it). The child should update with the parent changes for “free”. I will be cumbersome, but it might work.